# c structure member changing unexpectedly when order changes

Tags: c, structure

I have this structure, defined in my header file:

```
struct params
{
    size_t s;       
    float  f1;        
    float  f2;   
    int    i1;   
    float  f3;    
    gsl_matrix_float *gm;
};
```

I initialize the array and another `gsl_matrix_float` with:

```
gsl_matrix_float *another_gsl_matrix;
struct params p;
```

The elements are filled in one by one, for example

```
p.s=1;p.f1=0.2f;
```

During the program a totally unrelated function that works on `another_gsl_matrix` is run. But after that function, the value of `p.s` changes to `0`! The strange thing (for me, because of my lack of knowledge I guess!) is that when I change the order of the declaration of the members of the structure (moving `s` to the second, or any other, position in the structure declaration for example) there is no problem any more and all the values are fine! So I guess it isn't because of memory mis-management, for example pointing outside an array during that function.

I would be very grateful if you could help me understand what is going on here!

Comment: What does that totally unrelated function do ?

Comment: It works on a few other variables that share nothing with this structure at this point in the program. It works on a differently declared `gsl_matrix_float`. While I have not initialized the `p.gm` yet.

Comment: It sounds like `totally unrelated function` overwrite the memory of your struct but without the full code its hard to tell what is going on there.

Comment: May be you are accidentally accessing some address which happens to be holding that structure. We need to see the code. Also check compiler warnings.

Comment: I updated my last comment: It works on a differently declared `gsl_matrix_float`. While I have not initialized the `p.gm` yet.

Comment: Does all the p.s at the array changing to 0 or just few?

Comment: When it is declared first, `p.s` changes to zero, when it is declared second, everything is fine! Could you please elaborate more Ran?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Something's* corrupting your structure.

However, if you move members around within it, you're quite likely to introduce padding bytes which, when overwritten, have no effect on your other code.

C implementations are free to insert padding into structures between members, and after the final member, to allow for alignment issues. For example, you may end up with something like:

```
struct xyzzy {
    double zorkmid;   // offset 0, 8 bytes
    char   twisty;    // offset 8, 1 byte
                      // offset 9, 3 bytes padding
    int    plugh;     // offset 12, 4 bytes
    int    grue;      // offset 16, 4 bytes
                      // offset 20, 4 bytes padding.
                      // offset 24 for next zorkmid
};
```

Padding *between* members (never at the start) is usually to align members following that point, such as putting the `int` on a four-byte boundary. Padding *after* the last member is usually to ensure alignment of the *first* member in array situations, such as putting the `double` on an eight-byte boundary.

However, the *solution* is to find out what's corrupting the data and fix that.

Comment: I edited the question to explain what that function does. It works on another pointer to a `gsl_matrix_float`. That matrix has nothing to do with this structure at this point in the program.

Comment: @astroboy, that means you're most likely going beyond the bounds of your other matrix pointer which would corrupt memory. Corruption doesn't always seem logical. Since your question seemed to be about understanding why moving members changed behaviour, I think I answered that. If you want your actual problem solved (the corruption), that would be a different question.

Comment: You are correct, my problem was in understanding why this happens! I just checked, when I change the order of the declarations of the `another_gsl_matrix` and `p`, the problem is again fixed and removed! I understand now, thank you.

Comment: @astroboy, you _do_ realise that you haven't actually _fixed_ the problem by just moving things around. The actual corruption issue is still there. You may have _hidden_ it but it will almost certainly come back to haunt you at some point.

Comment: Yes! Exactly! By fixing I meant hiding I guess! I am reviewing the code to see where and how this happens! I am filling the `gsl_matrix` structure with data in that function! For some data it works while for others this problem comes up! I will have to find the cause. Thanks.